# Tkinter OptionManu title disappears in 2nd GUI window

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to open 2 GUIs with `OptionMenu` functions. GUI `window` works fine. However, GUI `window1` can't show the "demo" in the selection bar, in addition, the selected item will also not be placed on the selection bar.

What did I do wrong?

[image: screenshot]

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window1 = tk.Tk()

v = tk.StringVar()
v.set("demo")
optionMenu = tk.OptionMenu(window, v, "a", "b", "c")
optionMenu.pack()

optionMenu1 = tk.OptionMenu(window1, v, "1", "2", "3")
optionMenu1.pack()

window1.mainloop()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Only one `mainloop()` will run at a time. Calling `tk.Tk()` twice in the same tkinter script seldom works correctly. To create a (another) window use [`tk.Toplevel()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share variables between two instances of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, your second and subsequent windows need to be an instance of `Toplevel`.